# How can I improve the performance of a react-native-map with a large number of markers?

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

I use a reactive-native-map. Using markers on the map greatly decreases performance. How can I improve the performance of a map with a large number of markers?

ShouldComponentUpdate - doesn't help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out well to increase performance by making 2 step:

1. Add **tracksViewChanges={false}** for MapView.Marker
2. shouldComponentUpdate for Marker

```
<MapView.Marker 
  coordinate={{ latitude, longitude }} 
  tracksViewChanges={false}
>
   <View> ... </View>
</MapView.Marker>
```

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
        return nextProps.latitude !== this.props.latitude && nextProps.longitude !== this.props.longitude;
    }
```